# Why this path can't be converted to guides properly?

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape has a nice handy feature of converting an object to guides.

However, I have this path (or object), which can't be converted to guides properly, and I have no clue on why. Can you please help me understanding this?

[image]

When I convert this to guides, I got this result:

[image]

I expect having at least 3 more lines, just as in case of a simple rectangle:

[image]

Due to this, of course, I got bad results also when I wish to do boolean operations on this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape only converts completely straight lines to guides. If the segments are curved (i.e. has Bezier-handles on either side), they are ignored – even if they are curved only a tiny bit.

Select the two nodes on both sides of a curve and use the 'Make selected segments lines' button in the toolbar to remove the Bezier-handles and straighten it. You can select multiple segments before clicking the button. Also, if you have smooth-nodes, you may want to convert them to cusp-nodes first with the 'Make selected nodes corner' button, or it will distort the joining segment too.